# in Excel, how to find FWHM of data?

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have two columns X and Y, and Y is Gaussian type of peak, how can I find the Full-width half maximum (FWHM)?

I want to find all Y cells that are greater than half maximum and find the first and last corresponding X values, how can I do that? Is there a better way?

Comment: LWZ, do you have any feedback on this?

Answer (score -1):

**Question 1**: how can I find the Full-width half maximum (FWHM)?

According to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function

*FWHM = 2*sqrt(2*ln(2))*c*

Then, to find *c* you have to resort to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters

For that, you would like to explore some of the links from

https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+maximum+likelihood

**"Question" 2**: I want to find all Y cells that are greater than half maximum.

To be answered.

**"Question" 3**: ...

Idem.